# How to identify a component on a board?

Tags: rf, remote-control

I am trying to identify a component on a board of my roller shutter remote control.

Here is the board: 
[image]

The main component is very likely the one top-right, identified by `x1`.

I've tried to find what kind of components are labelled x without success. so I am unable to know what type of transmitter it is. I have referenced [How to Read a Schematic](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-read-a-schematic)

Googling any of the reference I could find on the board did not help either.

Could you help me find resources to be able to identify this?

Edit:
I am interested in this component to understand how I could build a similar control for all my roller shutters and control them via a computer (for instance my raspberrypi).

Comment: The real problem you'll likely have is the PIC12F508 microcontroller will contain code you won't know, possibly to generate some sort of rolling code.

Comment: thanks for the heads-up. How could you make sure of that? I'll read about rolling codes to understand precisely what you are talking about.

Comment: I am not aware of such function (but I have not setup the roller shutter myself), thanks for your additional explainations!

Comment: 5100 is probably the modulator and PLL controller IC. Controlled by the PIC 12F508. X1 will set the main frequency which will be multiplied by the PLL to a frequency in a legal to use radio band.

Comment: The 5100 is likely an Infineon TDA5100 ASK/FSK transmitter, or maybe a knock-off (since there is no manufacturer logo on that chip).

Comment: @Pigrew yup, seems reasonable output frequency is either 64 or 128 times 6.788 MHz crystal frequency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a quartz crystal with a resonant frequency of 6.788 MHz. Crystals are often identified with the X designation on schematics.